# Is it possible to move pan, rotate and zoom while running a modal operator in blender?

Tags: python, modal-dialog, viewport, operator-keyword, blender

When blender is running a modal the viewport cannot be moved.

Is there a way to stop this viewport blocking?

Comment: Maybe there’s a way to avoid the operator being modal? You can attach properties to objects, and put up a custom UI panel to allow ongoing display and editing of those properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can `PASS_THROUGH` any events to blender to handle, for example to let blender handle viewport `Pan` & `Zoom` while the modal is running you could do this :

```
    if event.type in ['MIDDLEMOUSE', 'WHEELUPMOUSE', 'WHEELDOWNMOUSE']:
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there's no *built-in* way to let the user navigate the viewport while you have your custom modal operator running.
The recommended way to do that is to re-implement the viewport navigation yourself, listening to keyboard and mouse events:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/678

You can also query the active KeyConfig (**bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.active**) to find out what keyboard keys are assigned to the nagivation, in case you want to use the same keys in your modal handler.